# How to run convert this batch script so it can run on command line and be called by python?

Tags: python, batch-file, command-line

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%i in (*.exr) do (
    set z=%%i 
    magick %%i !z:exr=pfm!
)
```

I have this batch script that i need to be able to run in python without having and calling the external batch file. Im trying to figure out how i can run this same script just on command line so i can us subprocess to do something like:

```
cmd = '''
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  for %i in (*.exr) do (
      set z=%i
      magick %i !z:exr=pfm!
  )
  ''' 

subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, cwd = convdir)
```

but cannot get it to work. What is the best method to go about this?

Comment: Delayed expansion cannot be enabled at the command line with the `SETLOCAL` command.  It has to be initialed with an option when cmd.exe is executed. `cmd /V:ON`. You also would be better off using a single line for the code as well. `for %i in (*.exr) do (set "z=%i" & magick "%i" "!z:exr=pfm!"`

Comment: Oh wait a minute. You don't need the string substitution.  You are just trying to replace the file extension.  Just use the command modifiers. `for %i in (*.exr) do magick "%i" "%%~ni.pfm"`  Not sure why you just wouldn't do this all in Python.

Comment: @Squashman Thankyou so much! Just removed the extra % and it works perfectly!

Comment: @KJ a pretty obvious typo.  The OP already knew they had to remove one percent symbol. You can see that in their code adjustment in their question.  Just forced habit to always type two percent symbols for the `FOR` variable.  I heavily use batch files and rarely ever do anything from the cmd prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to make PFM versions of EXR files. You can get rid of all that Microsoft CMD/BATCH nonsense and just do it with **ImageMagick**.

So, to convert IMAGE.EXR to IMAGE.PFM, just use:

```
magick mogrify -format PFM IMAGE.EXR
```

Or, alternatively, if you have a whole directory of EXR files and you want them all converted to PFM:

```
magick mogrify -format PFM *.EXR
```

Comment: Good Job Mark.  This is the reason I didn't post the batch file as an answer.  I assumed there was either a better way to do it in python.  Even better with Magick being able to use wildcards for the file names.

Comment: Mark, the OP requirement, as mentioned in both the title and body text was to run this from **python**. The fact that python is neither mentioned or implied in your answer suggests you're telling them to get rid of all that PYTHON rubbish too! Is that correct? or are they supposed to use `cmd = '''magick mogrify -format PFM *.EXR'''` or similar? Or should they use `Wand`, `python-magick`. or `PythonMagick`, or are they still required to use that Microsoft CMD.EXE rubbish?

Comment: @Compo My suggestion is definitely **not** to get rid of Python, only the unintuitive, arcane CMD/BATCH stuff. I am proposing `cmd = '''magick mogrify -format PFM *.EXR'''` followed by `subprocess...(cmd, ...)` in Python.

Comment: Just be aware @MarkSetchell, there really was no need to make unnecessary comments about BATCH, when it is not used at all in the OP's code, _(just internal cmd.exe commands)_. Your answer does however generally seem to depend upon using that arcane CMD program.